# How to create generic search for Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a data context in my Entity Framework project like this:

Sample entity

```
[Table("INVOICE")]
public class Invoice
{
   [Column("INVOICE_NUMBER")]
   public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
   ...
   ...
}
```

Data context

```
public interface IDataContext
{
    DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    DbSet<InvoiceLine> InvoiceLines { get; set; }
    DbSet<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
    DbSet<OrderLines> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a form on client side to users search by column and value.

```
{
  "searchTable": "INVOICE",
  "searchColumn": "INVOICE_NUMBER",
  "value": "1145587"
}
```

Should I find search criteria using reflection? Is there any way to do this for Entity Framework? (I have 40 or 50 entities)

Comment: You want to search across every single entity? That sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: `interface IDataContext` ??? A DbContext doesn't have such interfaces because it doesn't need them. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, for specific entity repositories (that's what DbSet<T> is). It's not a database model or connection. Exposing those repositories without their unit-of-work is a really bad idea.

Comment: What do you mean by `generic search`? Search across all fields? You can't do that with SQL in the first place, that's the job of search engines. Create a generic filter component form? ORMs like EF Core don't deal with UI issues. You'll have to build this yourself. You can use reflection to find the DbSets in a DbContext and then the properties of each type. Or you can ask a DbContext for its metadata through its [DbContext.Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.model?view=efcore-5.0) property